# I want to know about autocompletion and shortcuts in eclipse on Mac os

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm having issues with my macbook , in windows I was using "syso+control+space" to write this statement "System.out.println()" but in mac It doesn't work even with command button it will show up Spotlight search of the Mac . so can any one help me with it and where can I find all the shortcuts and autocompletion in eclipse .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Keys
```

Mac:

```
Eclipse > Preferences > General > Keys
```

But you might also want to take a look at or even change the templates you can use (for-each statement etc.):

```
Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates
```

Also check if the templates are activated at all:

```
Preferences > Java > Editor > Advanced
```

You need to have at least the `Java Proposals` activated

Answer (score 1):

Auto complete (Content Assist) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on Mac OS X.

Look in the Preferences in 'General > Keys' for the key bindings.